# Winter Bash on MO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stackexchange, winter-bash

I noticed that the Stack Exchange sites are having a [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/), and one of my friends received a hat on MSE. Why isn't this on MO? It'll be fun to have something like that here, wouldn't it? (I suspect this is because MO doesn't have a ".stackexchange.com" in its address, but I could be wrong.)

Comment: "wouldn't it?" No, it wouldn't.

Comment: @Andres I guess opinions can differ, but I personally think that it might be fun. Even if not, the FAQs say that one can opt to not have the hats! :-)

Comment: I think it would be fun! But we'd need to make sure that there is a Grinch hat, given for fast closing of questions or something like that. :-)  (Sorry, Andres! I couldn't resist)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Wrong. It would. HATZ!!!!

Comment: @nicael: For a user that contributed absolutely nothing to this website, I'd say that you're probably wrong and Andres is right.

Comment: @Asaf Why does it matter? I love the hatz on the rest of the SE sites. Just a few of them consist of serious professors who don't love the hatz ;) Yeeee!

Comment: You don't have to be "a serious professor" to dislike these things. I enjoy plenty of nonsensical shenanigans, but not this sort of "funtime activity". And please stop writing "hatz". 1337z0r sp33k ist ub3rk00l, amirite?

Comment: It seems to me that it could be useful if the decision of hats or no hats (including whether to display *other* users’ hats) were up to the user, not the site. This would solve both the problem that some users here want them and some don’t, and the inconsistency that someone’s hard-earned hats vanish when moving across sites.

Comment: Oh. As I learned on http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245191 , it actually already works that way, except that a site may also choose to veto all hat activity altogether. So the question is whether it would be acceptable for MO to move to the less strict “the site has hats, but they’re off by default” category.

Comment: Hats? I've seen this before. Isn't it where we all wear hats and then at the end of 100 days all commit suicide because of induction? (I may possibly be thinking of something else)

Comment: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/the-blue-eyed-islanders-puzzle

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I know, I may just possibly have not been serious

Comment: My personal (rather neutral) stance about "hats" can be seen on other metas; I just want to point out that also having hats of by default can have consequence for the site in general, as some users might do (potentially disruptive) things to get a hat.

Comment: What certain people in certain countries or regions may like, can easily put off
many others with different backgrounds. Given this, I think it is wise that MO
as a serious site with a global userbase does not participate in the event
discussed here.

Comment: @quid: It seems that this behavior happens either way; it's best not to give it any positive reinforcements in the form of hats. The only hats on this site should be `\hat` and `\widehat`.

Comment: Maybe we need to forbid them, too. Please @Asaf do not start signing your posts with $$\huge{\widehat{\text{Asaf}}}$$

Comment: @quid, very well. $$\qquad \Huge\widehat{\scr A\frak saf}$$

Comment: @quid and Asaf Karagila, this is why I come here, for silly fun times.

Comment: @JoelR: You forgot to sign your name, so let me do it for you. $\Large\widehat{\hat{\frak J}\check{o}\hat{e}\ell}$

Comment: I guess this question was sorta stupid, considering that MO is a serious site. I was simply curious.

Comment: There are other sites that are not really less serious that do have it. It was not an unreasonable question to ask.

Comment: @YemonChoi I just wanted to say that I come back to this thread every couple of months just to read your joke again. It's the funniest thing I've read in my life.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Somewhat before the start of the Winter Bash, the SE team contacts the per-site moderators to ask if the site wants to participate in the event or not (this year the default assumption being that the site participates, differing from  last year's practice).

The reason that MO does not participate is  (almost surely) that its moderators decided the site does not want to participate and communicated this decision to SE. Note that also last year MO did not participate for reasons along the lines given above. This has nothing to do with the domain name; stackoverflow.com has hats while a site with URL [something].stackexchange.com domain might not have them (I did not search for an example, but as explained at the start it would be possible).

To sum this up: on the technical side there is no issue at all, MO could have hats; it was simply decided against having them for this year.

Comment: The last sentence is incorrect. Each site has a choice between opt-in, out-out, or nothing.

Comment: In which precise way is the last sentence incorrect. What is "nothing" supposed to mean? In some sense, the information I gave concerns exactly the case when nothing is done by a site.

Comment: You claim that the event is opt-out. This is not true. On some (most) sites it is opt-out, on some sites it is opt-in, and some sites do not participate at all. This is a three-way choice made by the moderators of the site. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245191 .

Comment: My entire post is about the event on a per site basis (that is the concerned entity is "the site"), and so is this last sentence. The event *for a site* was opt-out in that a non-reply of its moderators would have been taken as a "yes, the site participates" (as opposed to a "no" like it was last year). What happens on a site on a per user basis is a different question that I did not mean to address at all. Anyway, thank you for pointing out the risk for confusion, I will update the post later to make clear what I meant, and psssibly give the *additional* you provide.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Comment: You should ask everybody, shouldn't you? As for me, I would not mind participating (except that they don't have the only one I would choose - "I never wear any hats").

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I am not sure why you post this comment here. Are you telling this to me? (I did not decide anything here; you might talk to the moderators about it, i.e. ask on the other answer.) Or are you asking my opinion? (I think the way the decision was made was reasonable, I have no objection at all. Where I did decide on this I asked the community; but also that community is much newer so its preferences were less clear in advance.)

Comment: @quid Sorry you are right, I should rather place this comment after Todd's answer. But this is more a joke than anything else anyway...

Answer (score 10):

I'll just add that [quid is correct](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2054/14094). The moderators were asked in 2013 whether MO wanted to participate in Winter Bash, and we declined. We thought it would not be wise, as it would be sure to turn off some of our esteemed users who do not come here for silly fun times. We were invited again this year by the StackExchange team, who essentially asked "we don't suppose you've changed your minds, have you?" and we of course said 'no'.

Some of the comments below the question seem to corroborate our suspicions which led to our decision.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Comment: I am now considering adding "I do not come here for silly fun times" to my profile :)

Comment: I can't say that I don't come here (and MSE) for silly fun times. But I can say that the hats are not fun.

Comment: I think we can also safely infer that Joel David Hamkins likes hats: http://www.unomaha.edu/logic/pictures/rutgers05/dsc01854_lar.jpg

Comment: Awesomeeeeeeeeeee!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, it has to be said that it's a pretty bad-ass hat. Sort of reminds me of the hats worn by Polish set theorists circa 1925, as in this photo: http://apprendre-math.info/history/photos/Mazur_Ulam.jpeg

Comment: To me the overall outfit reminds the angels from the lovely movie, "The Adjustment Bureau".

Answer (score 5):

I like the winter Bash, and several years ago I was even a champion in terms of numbers of hats in the TCS sister site. But I can understand that some mathematicians do not share my enthusiasm. It took decades to have an analog of Nobel prize in mathematics so it may take decades (if at all) for winter bash to be embraced on MO.

Comment: There is (was?) a Vinter stadium in Beer-Sheva, which could be treated as a וינטר ב"ש, if one is so inclined.

Comment: Only 5 hats so far...as a former champion?! I am a newcomer and have already twice as many. :-)

Comment: congratulations, quid!

Comment: Somehow it would not have occurred to me to compare Winter Bash to the Fields Medal. ;-)

Comment: I would like MO to participate in Winter Bash.