# How to wear my Winter bash hat

Tags: support, winter-bash

I have noticed a link on my Mathoverflow page linking a webpage that explains an event called [Winter bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/). I have earned already earned some hat which I am using on different stack exchange communities. My question is:

**Can I also wear my hat on MathOverflow? If so, how do I do it?**

Comment: I am not sure MO participates in Winter Bash: [Winter Bash on MO?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2053)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The moderation team is asked each year whether MO is going to participate in Winter Bash, and we've consistently declined. We had a discussion about it [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2053/winter-bash-on-mo?noredirect=1&lq=1). So, no hats, at least not so far.

There are actually several levels of Winter Bash participation for SE sites, explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245153/can-other-people-see-my-hats-even-if-i-hate-them/245191#245191). We haven't publicly discussed these different levels at MO meta before, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

There were a lot of curmudgeons (I among them) who were resistant to migrating to the 2.0 StackExchange platform.  A major reason was the concern that community participation would drop dramatically, and another was that the forum culture would change for the worse.  There were a number of minor reasons as well.

Fortunately, the forum has continued to this day ("But for how much longer?", as I ring my curmudgeon bell) and the culture changes have not been as drastic as I anticipated.  I think hats run counter to the culture here and so advise against it.  However, my presence has been tolerated here, so in the season of goodwill, I will grit my teeth and likewise tolerate an occasional hat.  I don't know if it is possible to activate them here on MathOverflow, or how to do so.

Gerhard "Is Winter Bash Over Yet?" Paseman, 2016.12.23.

Comment: I like curmudgeons ... Who doesn't?

Comment: Not my place to argue for or against hats here. From an anthropological perspective, hats are part of the network's rites of intensification. Sites like to be involved because they create and reinforce a sense of community. I'm pleased to have MathOverflow part of the network whether y'all feel like part of the larger community or not. You belong here and we respect your preference to opt out.

Comment: Thank you @Jon and Tintin. In case it isn't clear, the above is my sole opinion, but I believe is shared by many in the community. We curmudgeons are glad to contribute our social presence and pressure toward the common good at a moderated pace.  Those wishing to join the Curmudgeon Bash Winter Bash Party and Potluck may edit below the post signature to sign up. Gerhard "It's Really A Committee Meeting" Paseman, 2016.12.23.